# Ulam spiral and triangular numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there any explanation for the twister-like pattern build by triangular numbers $$\Delta_n = \frac{n\cdot(n+1)}{2}$$ in the [Ulam Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral)?

Here for $1,\ldots,100$:

[image]

Here's a picture with many more turns of the spiral, at which point the pattern seems to have settled on $17$ "arms."  Why $17$?

[image: bigger spiral]
<sub>(source: [mathforum.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20161104091149/http://mathforum.org/mathimages/imgUpload/thumb/Triangularnumbers.gif/300px-Triangularnumbers.gif))</sub>

Here are two of these arms:
$$10, 28, 55, 91, 136, 190, 253, 325,...$$
and
$$6, 21, 45, 78, 120, 171, 231, 300,...$$

Comment: The intuitive idea is that triangular numbers exhibit quadratic growth, which means that these numbers "should" lie nicely on Ulam's spiral.

Comment: Rewrite the formula as $\frac{n^2 + n}{2}$. Also compare the behavior of the square numbers.

Comment: @Wojowu Well, but "to lie nicely" means not necessarily a "twister".

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "twister-like pattern."

Comment: It loos like a whirlwind (tornado, twister...) from above: http://mathforum.org/mathimages/imgUpload/thumb/Triangularnumbers.gif/300px-Triangularnumbers.gif

Comment: @GeMir, ah thanks, that helps.  I've added that figure to your question, along with an observation about the number of arms, which struck me as curious.  If you don't like the added question, feel free to remove it.  But I think it might serve as a spur for someone to explain what's going on.  (If I can find the time, I'll give it some thought myself, but I suspect someone'll beat me to it.)

Comment: @GeMir: I suggest you isolate one or two "arms" and give the sequence of integers that comprise each one. There is probably a pattern that will shed light on why there are $17$ arms.

Comment: @GeMir, see http://oeis.org/A060544 and http://oeis.org/A081266 for the two sequences you added.  (The OEIS is the go-to site anytime you have a sequence of integers.)

Comment: @GeMir: Are you sure about those two "arms"? The sequence of triangular numbers is,$$1, 3, \color{red}{6}, \color{blue}{10}, 15,  \color{red}{21}, \color{blue}{28}, 36,  \color{red}{45}, \color{blue}{55}, 66,  \color{red}{78}, \color{blue}{91}, 105,  \color{red}{120}, \color{blue}{136}, 153,\dots$$ where the blue numbers give your first arm and the red ones your second. The uncolored is easily a third. Doesn't your picture show $17$ arms?

Comment: @BarryCipra: I think there are three primary "arms" that split into $17$ sub-arms. Kindly see my [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336443/ulam-spiral-and-triangular-numbers#comment2754565_1336443).

Answer (score 1):

I proved on my blog that there will in fact be 17 arms of this spiral. In fact my proof shows the arms will eventually straighten out and even bend in the other direction when the picture zooms out enough. Any chance you can make this happen? Here's the post:
http://mathbabe.org/2015/07/22/the-17-armed-spiral-within-a-spiral/

Comment: A related post from Dec 1, 2023, ["Why Do Square-Free Numbers Make Spirals?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4817142/4781) which the OP deleted shortly after.